# Profile 30a or 35b VDSL2 Modem

Tags: ethernet, dsl

We are looking to replace our current integrated VDSL Modem/Router (a horrid Vodafone branded Technicolor router with no modem mode) with a separate modem. We already have routing and Wi-Fi handled by dedicated devices.

I have been looking at the [Draytek Vigor 130](https://www.draytek.co.uk/products/business/vigor-130#specifications), but as with the old Huawei EchoLife HG612 modems and ECI B-focus (which you can now only pick up second hand), these are only [Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSL#Profiles) 17a (100Mbps).

If I'm going to buy a modem now though, I want it to at least support [Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSL#Profiles) 30a (200Mbps) if not [Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSL#Profiles) 35b (300Mbps) and/or G.fast (gigabit), so I don't have to buy another modem in a year or two's time. Even better would be if it had PoE support.

The problem is, I'm finding it remarkably difficult to find out what products support which profiles. For instance the [Netgear DM200 spec page](https://www.netgear.co.uk/home/products/networking/dsl-modems-routers/DM200.aspx#tab-techspecs) doesn't say anything about which profile it supports (though you can infer it is [Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSL#Profiles) 17a based on the 100Mbps download speed (mentioned in the text, not in the specification sheet).

All of the other devices I've found so far have been integrated modem/routers, and I don't want to have to contend with double natting. One option might be an integrated modem/router which has a 'modem mode' but I expect this would make it rather expensive, having to pay for lots of functionality that isn't needed.

What options should I be considering?

<sub>I am in the U.K. but this question should be relevant worldwide, as there is nothing special about VDSL2 in the U.K.</sub>

Comment: 1) 'having to pay for lots of functionality that isn't needed' is rarely an issue in real life. The manufacturers of the integrated gateways (i.e., modem+router) use the same processor for both functions (i.e., 'cheap') so it really doesn't drive your price up much, since their economies of sale on the gateway devices are so much larger than separate modems and separate routers that their price is driven down.

Comment: There's a big difference between paying £300 for an all-the-bells-and-whistles modem/router just for decent modem functionality, and a £60 dedicated modem, when you've already paid for a £150 router and a £150 Wi-Fi.

Comment: I didn't think location was particularly relevant. VDSL2 is a worldwide standard. Ofcom no longer regulates what devices can be used, as long as it's CE marked and fit for the EU, it's fine in the UK too. Openreach is already trialling G.fast, so 35b may be skipped, but it may still find a place outside of city centres. It would be even better if the suggested modem also supported G.fast, but I didn't want to muddy the water too much, and 30a is my most likely upgrade path.

Comment: The problem with "200mbps" and "300mbps" as search terms is that search engines have no way to differentiate VDSL speed from Wi-Fi speed, so they pull in hoards of old  802.11n modem/routers. I've already been down that route, and didn't get far. My Google Foo isn't *that* bad. *8')